# How to Measure Image Quality in an Objective Way

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-processing, perceived-quality

I need a method to measure image quality via computer programming (like Python). I'm doing this so as to compare quality of multiple images. I have found stuff like NMSE, PSNR and SSIM, but don't fully understand them, and am not sure which one is the best or if I should use multiple.

I was wondering what is the best method to measure image quality?

Comment: The "best quality measure for flour" on its own doesn't exist – what's the best flour? That depends on what you want to bake, pizza, cake or bread. Same for image quality measures. You need to very clearly defined which kind of images you're talking about, and for which purpose you need to measure "quality" (whatever that means).

Comment: Ok I understand so that means that different metrics are good for different use cases. I'm looking more for the use case of like color depth of image, sharpness of image, tones of image like in image histogram, that sort of thing. Is there a recommendation for that particular use case?

Comment: Color depth, sharpness, and tones are not use cases, they are *features*. Quality typically implies a measure of usefulness for an application. Determining which measure is best will involve some comparison (ideally quantitatively) - can you define a cost function? If your application involves object detection, a metric could be the number of correct object detections from a ML algorithm (or a human viewing the images). Image quality could also refer to how similar an image is to a ground truth, where distortions appear from lack of contrast/bitdepth, optical artifacts (e.g. vignetting), etc..

Comment: If there were an objective image quality measure, then there would really be an `enhance` command.